# to_sentence and html_safe, together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitization

Here's the string I want:

```
<a href="/pugs/1-baxter">Baxter</a> and <a href="/pugs/2-sofia">Sofia</a>
```

Here's the code I'm using to output that:

```
<%= @pugs.collect {|p| link_to(p.name, pug_path(p))}.to_sentence %>
```

Unfortunately the output is getting encoded:

```
 &lt;a href=&quot;/pugs/1-baxter&quot;&gt;Baxter&lt;/a&gt; and &lt;a href=&quot;/pugs/2-sofia&quot;&gt;Sofia&lt;/a&gt;
```

I've tried using `html_safe` and `raw`, but they don't seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 9):

As of Rails 5, there's a `to_sentence` view helper (different from `Array#to_sentence`) that does this.

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-to_sentence):

> **to_sentence**(array, options = {})
>   Converts the array to a comma-separated sentence where the last element is joined by the
>   connector word. This is the html_safe-aware version of ActiveSupport's
>   Array#to_sentence.

Use it like: `<% to_sentence(@pugs.collect {|p| link_to(p.name, pug_path(p))}) %>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @pugs.collect {|p| link_to(p.name, pug_path(p))}.to_sentence.html_safe %>
```

Comment: It actually works. There is probably something else wrong then :)

Comment: This is bad. You're marking the whole string as safe. If you set p.name to something malicious you'll see that your method allows it to get through unescaped into the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a span and use a helper:

```
  def content_link_to(name,path=nil,options=nil)
    content_tag :span do
      link_to name, path, options
    end
  end
```

And use it as follows:

```
<%= @pugs.collect {|p| content_link_to(p.name, pug_path(p))}.to_sentence %>
```

Comment: Adding extra HTML around those links just to output html safe content seems overkill. I just want Rails to output actual HTML instead of escaping it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put it in a translation, you can add `_html` at the end of the translation key like this:

```
<%= t(".public_rooms_html", rooms: to_sentence(@public_rooms.map { |room| link_to(room.to_s, room) })) %>
```